# How do I re-populate the navigation pane in microsoft access 365 through VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, microsoft365

I just recently upgraded from Microsoft Access 2010 to Microsoft Access 365.  Me along with a handful of other users need to navigate a Microsoft Access instance and easily change databases (there's 150+ on the server).  In Microsoft Access 2010, it was easy.  Just go into File, Connection Settings, Change database name, and the navigation pane populates with the corresponding stored procedures, tables, etc.  Now, it's not as easy.  This time, when the instance opens, I have a form that opens up that contains a combo box.  This combo box contains all the database names on the server, based on SQL initializations in VBA.  ("Select name from sys.sysdatabases").

So my question:  Based on database name selection, how can I populate the navigation pane with the tables, stored procedures, etc. that the SQL database has?

Answer (score 1):

You were using an Access ADP (Access Data Project) to connect to different SQL Server databases with Access 2010.

Unfortunately, ADP projects were deprecated and removed with Access 2013. With Access 2013 and newer it is not possible anymore to do what you intend.